# why C style code is faster than C++ style code

Tags: c++, c

After implementing the algorithm problem in C ++, I was curious and coded in C.

I realized that the C implementation itself has a lot of code and a lot of messy and unnecessary parts.

For C ++ implementations, the speed was 8ms and C was 0ms.

And the one I implemented in C had a longer code length, but the size was half the size of a C ++ file.

I am curious as to what kind of difference there is. Please let me know

C code

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1000
char *iterator;

bool assertNotNull(char* input) {
    bool ret = true;

    if (input == NULL)
        ret = false;

    return ret;
}

char *reverse(char *input) {
    char head = *(input);
    char *ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_LENGTH);
    memset(ret, '\0', 1);

    if (head == 'w' || head == 'b') {
        char str[2] = { head , '\0' };
        memcpy(ret, str, 2);
    }

    else {
        char *leftTop = reverse(++iterator);
        char *rightTop = reverse(++iterator);
        char *leftBot = reverse(++iterator);
        char *rightBot = reverse(++iterator);

        char str[2] = { 'x','\0' };
        memcpy(ret + strlen(ret), str, 2);
        memcpy(ret + strlen(ret), leftBot, strlen(leftBot)+1);
        memcpy(ret + strlen(ret), rightBot, strlen(rightBot)+1);
        memcpy(ret + strlen(ret), leftTop, strlen(leftTop)+1);
        memcpy(ret + strlen(ret), rightTop, strlen(rightTop)+1);

        free(leftTop);
        free(leftBot);
        free(rightTop);
        free(rightBot);
    }

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int caseNum;
    char *input = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(MAX_LENGTH));
    char **ret = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*MAX_LENGTH);

    scanf("%d", &caseNum);

    for (int i = 0; i < caseNum; i++) {
        scanf("%s", input);
        iterator = input;
        *(ret + i) = (char*)malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
        *(ret + i) = reverse(input);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < caseNum; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *(ret + i));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

C++ Code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string reverse(string::iterator &it) {
    char head = *(it);
    string ret = "";

    if (head == 'w' || head == 'b') {
        ret += head;
    }

    else {
        string leftTop = reverse(++it);
        string rightTop = reverse(++it);
        string leftBot = reverse(++it);
        string rightBot = reverse(++it);

        ret += 'x' + leftBot + rightBot + leftTop + rightTop;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int caseNum;
    string input;
    vector<string> ret;

    cin >> caseNum;

    for (int i = 0; i < caseNum; i++) {
        cin >> input;
        string::iterator it = input.begin();
        ret.push_back(reverse(it));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < caseNum; i++) {
        cout << ret[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

///

This was an algorithmic problem with quad tree flipping. (https://algospot.com/judge/problem/read/QUADTREE)

Example Input is

```
4 // counts of case
w
xbwwb
xbwxwbbwb
xxwwwbxwxwbbbwwxxxwwbbbwwwwbb
```

Example Output is

```
w
xwbbw
xxbwwbbbw
xxwbxwwxbbwwbwbxwbwwxwwwxbbwb
```

and 
C code performance time: 0ms
C++ code performance time: 8ms
This time is calculated from the algorithmic problem site(algospot).

I am very grateful for all the answers and for letting me realize that my question is wrong!!!

(I apologize for awkward English. :) )

Comment: What exact compiler have you used (which version)? What exact optimization flags have you used? At last, be sure to have a benchmark requiring at least half a second of CPU time (otherwise, the measurements tend to be meaningless).

Comment: `ret += 'x' + leftBot + rightBot + leftTop + rightTop;` is not efficient. Do the same as in C, use `+=` or `append` after reserving the size of the string. clang-tidy would scream at this.

Comment: At least in debug mode, iterators will have the overhead of a range check.

Comment: I guess this is caused by std::cin and std::cout, which is slower than scanf and printf.

Comment: Comparing performance of implementations is half of truth. In development for industrial applications, we consider also the time (= costs) of development itself, the costs of staff needed for this (and probable maintenance efforts). In this case, C++ mostly beats C... ;-)

Comment: Notice, that you use containers without reserving space, so they reallocate memory every time they need. Allocating memory isn't cheap operation and that could be part of an issue.

Comment: The C version is using a global variable :( Not quite the same code. What's the input for testing?

Comment: 0ms is certainly below the measurement error threshold, and 8ms could be as well for all we know. In all likelihood you are not measuring correctly. You need a larger data set, and you should only measure the algorithm itself (not any input or output).

Comment: Use `'\n'` instead of `std:endl`, wherever you don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Namely: flushing of the stream, which has pretty significant performance impact.

Comment: @GenoChen Once you unlink the C++ iostreams from the C iostreams (with `sync_with_stdio (false)` there speeds are very comparable.

Comment: I give up. Both pieces of code segfault for me.

Comment: At least the c++ code is invalid. It asserts for input as simple as `1`, `abc`.

Comment: There were a lot of problems with my question and code. But I am very glad to know that thanks to the help of many people. Thank you very much for the comments!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't force a flush:

```
cout << ret[i] << endl;
```

That is really inefficient forcing the stream to flush every time. Rather simply use the `\n`;

```
cout << ret[i] << `\n';
```

Also because C++ tried to maintain backward compatibility with C the C++ iostream are linked to the C iostreams. It is expensive to keep them in sync. If you are not using the C iostreams in your C++ application best to un-sync them:

```
int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    // Your code
}
```

Building a string like this is not the most efficient way of doing it:

```
ret += 'x' + leftBot + rightBot + leftTop + rightTop;
```

Do what you did in C:

```
ret += 'x';
ret += leftBot;
ret += rightBot;
ret += leftTop;
ret += rightTop;
```

You may also want to make sure the string does not resize. In the C version you have a max size. Why not give the C++ the benefit of knowing this to prevent re-allocation.

```
std::string ret;
ret.reserve(MAX_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!!!. One thing I'm curious about is the "building string".

why {ret += 'x'; ret+= leftBot} is recommended over {ret += 'x' + leftBot }?
Thank you again for your answer!!.

Comment: @김동환 Well the `x + leftBot` must create a new temporary string. So we have an extra memory allocation. Then when you do `ret += Stuff;` it copies `Stuff` into ret. Now that the temporary has been used we must destroy it. The creation of a temporary happens for each of `operator +` calls. So in your expression `'x' + leftBot + rightBot + leftTop + rightTop` You create 4 temporary objects and destroy them. Allocating/destroying memory is expensive and you have needlessly done it 4 times.

Comment: @김동환 The `ret += leftBot;` copies the content of `leftBot` into ret. If there is enough space in `ret` no extra allocation is required. Which is why I suggest you use `reserve()` to make sure that an extra allocation is never required.

Comment: @김동환 An accept would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It has been a great help!!!!!!!